# Webpage provides connection string and query string as parameters

Tags: asp.net

I am working on the web page that suppose to do the following:

When the user open this page he will be able to:

1. Type in (or copy and paste from somewhere) the connection string to the server and database into  "k-textbox1".
2. Type in or copy from somewhere the Select statement like this: Select Filed 1from Table. into another "k-textbox2".
3. Click the button "show results" and have the resulted record set displayed in the area (ListView) on the same form.

I have all the textboxes, buttons and functions on the form in .js file that does simple thing - I type in the query text, click the "show results" and have the same "sentence" displayed in the Listview.

I need the following:

New class that has a method where we pass in the connection string and the query that were typed in as I said above.

Add the class to the DAL layer .(That is why I provided the initial code at the beginning of the question.  )

Add a method to the Object factory that will return an instance of that new class.
Create a method in  web service that will be called from JS to get the query results.

The method will then return a list of strings that are the results of the query.

If there is an error (like the SQL statement was bad or the connecting string was bad), we’ll want to return and display that message to the user.

So far I have

1.namespace in DAL:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace CGI.QALog.DAL
{
    public class ADOConnection
    {
    }
}
```

2. The function that I have created to do simple displayed the textbox data in the listBox is in .js file looking like that:

   ```
   onEditDialogShowResults = function () {
   LookupQuery = $("#LookupQuery").val();
   $('#LookupResultsListView').text(LookupQuery)
   ```

Comment: Where are you stuck?  This sort of reads like a homework assignment.  What part is giving you trouble?

Comment: What happens when a user types in `delete from table` into your form?